# Bigquery Innerjoin is running for very long time

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, inner-join, query-performance

I have two tables of size 13 GB and 1 GB. Table 1 has 12 Million rows * 1.6k columns and table two has 5k rows * 160 columns.
I am performing an inner join on these two tables to find all the matching records like the example query below, but the query seems to be running for a very long time, for hours. The resulting join has a table size of 29 GB with 9 Million rows.
How should I improve the run time of this operation? I did read clustering the tables improves performance. Is that the best option for this case?

```
SELECT  
* 
FROM 
`myproject.table1` as t1
INNER JOIN
`myproject.table2` as t2
ON
(
t1.Camp1ID = t2.ID
OR t1.Camp2ID = t2.ID
OR t1.Camp3ID = t2.ID
OR t1.Camp4ID = t2.ID
OR t1.Camp5ID h = t2.ID
OR t1.Camp6ID = t2.ID
OR t1.Camp7ID = t2.ID
OR t1.Camp8ID = t2.ID
OR t1.Camp9ID = t2.ID
OR t1.Camp10ID = t2.ID
OR t1.Camp11ID = t2.ID
OR t1.Camp12ID = t2.ID
OR t1.Camp13ID = t2.ID
OR t1.Camp14ID = t2.ID
OR t1.Camp15ID = t2.ID
OR t1.Camp16ID = t2.ID
)
Where
t1.Date BETWEEN  PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%y', t2.StartDate) AND  PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%y', t2.EndDate)
```

Camp ID's are not unique in those columns, multiple rows have the same camp ID's.

Comment: Your text mentions two tables but your question only one.  You are doing a self join on a table using `or` and 20 columns.  Do you have any idea how many rows this might produce?  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what logic you want would all help.

Comment: sorry its table 2, not the self-join. the desired result is to have a table with all the columns in two tables with matching rows.

Answer (score 2):

Some improvements (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(parsed_StartDate, parsed_EndDate)
FROM `myproject.table1` as t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT * , 
  PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%y', t2.StartDate) parsed_StartDate, 
  PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%y', t2.EndDate) parsed_EndDate 
  FROM `myproject.table2`
) as t2
ON t2.ID IN (t1.Camp1ID,t1.Camp2ID,t1.Camp3ID,t1.Camp4ID,t1.Camp5ID,t1.Camp6ID,t1.Camp7ID,t1.Camp8ID,t1.Camp9ID,t1.Camp10ID,t1.Camp11ID,t1.Camp12ID,t1.Camp13ID,t1.Camp14ID,t1.Camp15ID,t1.Camp16ID)
AND t1.Date BETWEEN parsed_StartDate AND parsed_EndDate
```

Comment: This query improves run time ~ by 30%.

Comment: yes, I would expected such result - mostly because of pre-parsing dates

Comment: but this query output has 31k records lesser to the output of the query I had mentioned in the question.

Comment: Try replace AND with WHERE - as it is in you query

Answer (score 0):

> I did read clustering the tables improves performance. Is that the best option for this case?

If you're implying that you didn't set up proper indices, and do self-joins on a 13GB table, I think I found your problem. Add individual non-clustered indices on every one of the columns involved in this, those camp IDs and the ID field itself.

And after that, remove all hard coded camp ID columns, and set up a properly normalized one-to-many relationship with an intermediary table, and join through that instead.

Comment: And properly set up the indices as well, include all needed columns in the index, otherwise it will have to look up the data anyway.